# "302 MP3 Not Ok" Error when embedding Soundcloud into Wordpress

Tags: wordpress, soundcloud

Running WP 4.2.4 and until the last month, had no issues with embedding MP3's from Soundcloud. Now getting a consistent "302 Detected, MP3 Not Ok" which prevents the tracks from playing.
Logged in from different machine and no such issue. Can't understand why the error code is present on specific hardware?

Comment: is this a general issue or for a specific track? show more code, the track-id, please.